# Angular verify value inside an array from the result another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to check a value inside an array, from the result of another array, and put a key inside the object so that I can make an ngfor on my screen and bring those values, but I'm not getting it. I need to create the volumes key inside the server array, the getVolumes endpoint returns me an object array containing the attachments key and inside it the server_id key, where is the server id that that volume is located on. I need to bring only the volumes that contain a value for the name key, but the result is an empty array. Can you help me?

My code

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    forkJoin(this.serverService.getServer(), 
    this.storage.getVolumes())
    .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
    .subscribe(([servers, volumes]) => {
      this.volumes = volumes;
      this.servers = servers.map((server) => ({
        ...server,
        volumes: this.volumes.map((volume) => {
          volume['attachments'].map((volumeId) => {
            console.log(volumeId)
            volumeId['server_id'] === server.id ? volumeId : 'None';
            console.log(this.servers)
          })
        })
      }))
    })
  }
```

My html code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let volume of volumes">
                <tr *ngIf="volume?.name.length > 2" (click)="selectVolume = volume">
                  <td>  
                    <div class="user-info">
                      <div class="user-info__img">
                        <img src="./assets/img/storages.svg" alt="UserImg">
                      </div>
                      <div class="user-info__basic">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">{{volume.name}}</h5>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td >{{volume.size}} GB</td>

                  <td>
                    <span *ngFor="let attachedVolume of servers.volumes">
                      {{attachedVolume.name}}
                    </span>
                  </td>
</ng-container>
```

My Response from Volume API:

```
{
      "id": "939b1432-13f7-41ff-b9d2-908b25499c99",
      "name": "",
      "size": 10,
      "status": "in-use",
      "volume_type": "__DEFAULT__",
      "attachments": [
        {
          "id": "939b1432-13f7-41ff-b9d2-908b25499c99",
          "server_id": "1879f47f-1c5e-464b-bb76-e7cc13ef426e",
          "attachment_id": "5749f842-5dff-48ac-ac57-2a6bfb806ad5",
          "volume_id": "939b1432-13f7-41ff-b9d2-908b25499c99",
          "device": "/dev/vda",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "bd91e685-bdd4-4bb8-b25d-18e91f458fb8",
      "name": "Test01",
      "size": 20,
      "status": "in-use",
      "volume_type": "__DEFAULT__",
      "attachments": [
        {
          "id": "bd91e685-bdd4-4bb8-b25d-18e91f458fb8",
          "server_id": "1879f47f-1c5e-464b-bb76-e7cc13ef426e",
          "attachment_id": "f4cd9033-dd6e-4d47-88a7-904c267f162f",
          "volume_id": "bd91e685-bdd4-4bb8-b25d-18e91f458fb8",
          "device": "/dev/vdc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "97b800c5-1061-4a38-b7ec-c4528f248f72",
      "name": "",
      "size": 20,
      "status": "in-use",
      "volume_type": "__DEFAULT__",
      "attachments": [
        {
          "id": "97b800c5-1061-4a38-b7ec-c4528f248f72",
          "server_id": "b9c7e32a-bf99-4250-83cb-13523f9c1604",
          "attachment_id": "c0cd7598-69ba-4ce8-8407-aef68219a00d",
          "volume_id": "97b800c5-1061-4a38-b7ec-c4528f248f72",
          "device": "/dev/vda",
        }
      ]
    },
```

My Server API Response

```
{
      "id": "1879f47f-1c5e-464b-bb76-e7cc13ef426e",
      "name": "olakital",
      "flavor": {
        "id": "21f46a72-7f4f-40c5-9f1f-0100fadbc226",
        "disk": "10",
        "ram": "4000",
        "swap": "",
        "vcpus": "4"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "b9c7e32a-bf99-4250-83cb-13523f9c1604",
      "name": "teste01",
      "flavor": {
        "id": "59fc4d83-156d-4aa6-84a7-ea1c90d0fde5",
        "disk": "20",
        "ram": "8",
        "swap": "200",
        "vcpus": "4"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I really understand your request, you can filter for valid volumes (volumes with a not empty name) which have server_id as attachment. Try this code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    forkJoin(this.serverService.getServer(), 
    this.storage.getVolumes())
    .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
    .subscribe(([servers, volumes]) => {
      this.volumes = volumes;
      this.servers = servers.map((server) => ({
        ...server,
        volumes: volumes.filter(volume => volume.name && volume.attachments.some(attachment => attachment.server_id == server.id))

      }))
    })
  }

HTML: 

<span *ngFor="let server of servers "> 
    <span *ngFor="let attachedVolume of server.volumes "> 
         {{attachedVolume.name}}
    </span>
</span>
```

UPDATE:
What if you switch to this? in this way you can check directly which server the storage is allocated to:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    forkJoin(this.serverService.getServer(), 
    this.storage.getVolumes())
    .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
    .subscribe(([servers, volumes]) => {
      this.volumes = volumes.map(volume => ({
          ...volume,
          servers: servers.filter(server => volume.attachments.some(attachment => attachment.server_id == server.id))
       })),
      this.servers = servers;
    })
  }
```

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let volume of volumes">
    <tr *ngIf="volume?.name.length > 2" (click)="selectVolume = volume">
        <td>  
            <div class="user-info">
                <div class="user-info__img">
                    <img src="./assets/img/storages.svg" alt="UserImg">
                </div>
                <div class="user-info__basic">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">{{volume.name}}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td >{{volume.size}} GB</td>

        <td>
            <span *ngFor="let server of volume.servers">
              {{server.name}}
            </span>
        </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I changed a part of the code:

volumes: volumes.filter (volume => volume.attachments.some (attachment => attachment.server_id == server.id))

and now he is adding it as a key volume within my array of servers, but when performing ngFor in my HTML, he is not binding, and does not return an error. It just remains empty. Here is an image of my html code and log of the server array.

Servers array: https://imgur.com/a/48sKTBO

Html Code:
https://imgur.com/TCKOxtf

Comment: The problem is you are trying to access voumes property on array, servers.volumes, but servers is an array. You should first iterate on servers property then on volumes. I update my answer. Take a look

Comment: Got it. I did it and it really worked, but the name I need is the server and not the storage.
I changed my code to
        
volumes: volumes.filter (volume => volume.attachments.some (attachment => attachment.server_id == server.id ? server.name : ''))

And it didn’t work, it’s still empty, I still don’t understand what’s going on. : /

Comment: example: I have server A and it has a volume of ID ABC, the volume's ABC ID is the same as the ABC ID of server A, so I need to put the server.name in my html to show which server the storage is allocated to.
So I'm trying to do that
"volume.attachments.some(attachment => attachment.server_id == server.id ? server.name)"

Comment: Hi @Dave, does my answer resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi, its work for me. thank you so much \o/

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, I haven't fully tested this, but from what I gather and the data you've shown, it seems like when you're filtering the volumes based on the server id in the attachment, you're not returning the volume, essentially because nothing's being returned the volumes property in `this.servers` will be either an `empty array` or `undefined`;

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    forkJoin(this.serverService.getServer(), 
    this.storage.getVolumes())
    .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
    .subscribe(([servers, volumes]) => {
      this.volumes = volumes;
      this.servers = servers.map((server) => ({
        ...server,
        volumes: volumes.reduce((filteredVolumes, volume) => { 
            const found = volume.attachments
              .filter(attachment => attachment.name && attachment.server_id === server.id);

            if(!!found.length) {
              filteredVolumes.push(volume);
            }
         
            return filteredVolumes;
        }, [])
      }))
    })
  }
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this and it's returning me error: /

core.js:6241 ERROR TypeError: result.add is not a function
    at machine.component.ts:61
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at machine.component.ts:57
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at machine.component.ts:56
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)

Comment: sorry I've amended my answer, is I mistakenly wrote `result.add(...)` instead of `result.push(...)`

Comment: Hi, I ended up switching to .push, even though it still isn't creating the volumes key in my server array: /
image result https://imgur.com/hytizJ6